# Como faço para alinhar varias divs dentro de um contêiner?

Tags: html, css, front-end

Eu estou com um problema, estou tentando alinhar varias divs dentro de um contêiner, mais especificamente 3, o que desejo é deixa-las todas alinhadas uma do lado da outra, porém uma acaba indo para baixo e não sei como resolver isso, segue o código:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 764px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    border: 3px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
    ;
    
}

.img-wraper{
    width: 33.3%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 23.3%;
    padding-left: 23.3%;
    float: left;
   /* background-color: #ccc; */
    position: relative; 
    
}

.img{
    border: 2px solid black ;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="img-wraper">

            <div class="img" style="background-image:url('imagens/imagem1.jpg');"></div>
            
        </div> <!--img-wraper-->
        
        <div class="img-wraper">

            <div class="img" style="background-image:url('imagens/imagem1.jpg');"></div>
            
        </div> <!--img-wraper-->
        
        <div class="img-wraper">

            <div class="img" style="background-image:url('imagens/imagem1.jpg');"></div>
            
        </div> <!--img-wraper-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> <!--container-->

</body>
```

[image: Segue como está no navegador]

Comment: crie um exemplo funcional mostrando como está para entendermos melhor

Comment: @RicardoPontual ele até criou um exemplo 100% reproduzível. Mas faltou a formatação. Ele ainda não tem muita intimidade com o site. Ajudei editando a pergunta dele. Ficou filé!

Comment: agora sim, quando vi a pergunta só havia o codigo

Comment: Essas `<div>` possuem `margin` que influência no **Box Model** (*Modelo de Caixa*, https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) e acaba que a largura e altura do elemento sejam todas somadas, assim não cabendo no contêiner pai. Isso é a mesma coisa que você querer entrar de carro pela porta, seguindo o raciocínio o carro é grande e a porta é pequena, então o carro não vai entrar, a mesma coisa acontece no seu exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você dividiu o espaço exato do container entre as três `div`.

Até aí, tudo bem. O espaço de cada delas uma **pode ser** `33.3%`. Se quiser mais preciso, recomendo usar `33.33%`. Mas o principal problema é que **você colocou uma margem de `10px` nessas `div`**.

Para solucionar isso, pode usar a função `calc()` do próprio CSS. A ideia é que as suas `div` ocupem `33.3% - 20px`. Lembre-se que a margem é de `10px` em cada borda! Logo, a largura deve-se considerar `10px` à esquerda e `10px` à direita. Finalmente chegamos em `calc(33.3% - 20px)`.

> **Dica #1**: pela sintaxe do CSS, não deve-se omitir os espaços entre o operador. Isso é um erro de sintaxe: `calc(33.3%-20px)`.
>
> **Dica #2**: quando esse espaço extra é relacionado ao `padding` ou `border`, você pode simplesmente considerar essas propriedades no dimensionamento geral do elemento com `box-sizing: border-box;`.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 764px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    border: 3px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
    ;
    
}

.img-wraper{
    width: calc(33.3% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 23.3%;
    padding-left: 23.3%;
    float: left;
   /* background-color: #ccc; */
    position: relative; 
    
}

.img{
    border: 2px solid black ;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="img-wraper">

            <div class="img" style="background-image:url('imagens/imagem1.jpg');"></div>
            
        </div> <!--img-wraper-->
        
        <div class="img-wraper">

            <div class="img" style="background-image:url('imagens/imagem1.jpg');"></div>
            
        </div> <!--img-wraper-->
        
        <div class="img-wraper">

            <div class="img" style="background-image:url('imagens/imagem1.jpg');"></div>
            
        </div> <!--img-wraper-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> <!--container-->

</body>
```

> Leitura recomendada: [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/calc)